# How to display local time (considering timezone)?

Tags: javascript, datetime, time, timezone, localtime

I'm making a messenger and I need to display messages time in user timezone. Currently I have different times from server messages and client messages because of timezone.

When a message is created on a client datetime field is equal new Date():

```
function Message(sender) {
    ...
    this["datetime"] = new Date(); 
    ...
```

When a message is received from a server datetime field is a ctime which came from the server. And this code displays message time:

```
chatMessageTime.innerHTML = new Date(message["datetime"]).toLocaleString("ru", {
    "hour": "numeric",
    "minute": "numeric"
  });
```

And as I said before as a result I have times in different timezones. How to solve this problem? How to display user timezone for all messages?

Comment: So the server is storing times in different time zones, or are you converting them all to server time prior?

Comment: @Zze The server stores datetimes in unix time format.

Comment: @charlietfl So is it the server problem? Should the server store datetimes in UTC not in Unix time format?

Comment: @AlexanderShpindler: Unix time format (as long as you're doing it correctly) is defined to be in UTC. But it's your responsibility that if you are doing any conversion that conversion is done correctly.

Comment: Don't trust the client time setting, it can be anything. Use the server time for everything and keep it UTC. Only convert to "local" on the client and for display purposes only. Perhaps see [*Convert UNIX timestamp to date time*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24170933/convert-unix-timestamp-to-date-time-javascript).

Comment: @RobG Yes, of course. The server sets time by itself. My code is only for displaying time. I have problems with converting.

Comment: Then what you have should suit, noting that the options to *toLocaleString* are [*not supported by all browsers in use*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString#Browser_compatibility), they'll get the default which is entirely browser dependent.

Comment: It would be so cool if I'll simply get client time from his device:) But as I know browsers don't allow this access.

Answer (score 0):

In *javascript* dates are automatically shown in user's current language:
For ie., date "Feb 05 2017 23:08:23 GMT-0300" is shown as "Mon Feb 06 2017 00:08:23 GMT-0200" in my browser.

```
console.log(new Date('Sun Feb 05 2017 23:08:23 GMT-0300'));
```

Comment: Not necessarily, the output of *Date.prototype.toString* is entirely implementation dependent, though most browsers at least seem to have settled on the a version of [*RFC2822*](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#section-3.3). However, things like time zone indicators are inconsistently supported. The SO console seems to always use ISO 8601 with UTC, so no localisation at all.

Comment: Okey, thanks everyone for help. I decided to use a hack. During initialization of chat I calculate the difference between times and simply use it for displaying localtime.