# Unix time from API to normal format

Tags: javascript, time

I'm using openweathermap for my application https://openweathermap.org/current and I need to input the current time with weather in the city.

The time in the API in UNIX format. How I can input the time in application in normal format (h:m:s)

Line with date/time from API (dt....Time of data calculation, unix, UTC)

Below my JS code

```
    document.querySelector('#city').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {

        var city = $(this).val();
        if (city !== '') {

            $.ajax({

                url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + city + "&units=metric" +
                    "&APPID=bb037310921af67f24ba53f2bad48b1d",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    var widget = show(data);

                    $("#show").html(widget);

                    $("#city").val(' ');

                }

            });

        } else {
            $("#error").html("<div class='alert alert-danger text-center'><a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>Field cannot be empty</div>");
        }

    };
});


function show(data) {
    return "<h2>Current Weather for " + data.name + "," + data.sys.country + "</h2>" +
    "<h3><strong>Wind Speed</strong>: " + data.dt + "</h3>" +
        "<h3><strong>Weather</strong>: <img src='http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + data.weather[0].icon + ".png'>" + data.weather[0].main + "</h3>" +
        "<h3><strong>Description</strong>: " + data.weather[0].description + "</h3>" +
        "<h3><strong>Temperature</strong>: " + data.main.temp + "&deg;C</h3>" +
        "<h3><strong>Pressure</strong>: " + data.main.pressure + "hPa</h3>" +
        "<h3><strong>Humidity</strong>: " + data.main.humidity + " %</h3>" +
        "<h3><strong>Min. Temperature</strong>: " + data.main.temp_min + "&deg;C</h3>" +
        "<h3><strong>Max. Temperature</strong>: " + data.main.temp_max + "&deg;C</h3>" +
        "<h3><strong>Wind Speed</strong>: " + data.wind.speed + "m/s</h3>" +
        "<h3><strong>Wind Direction</strong>: " + data.wind.deg + "&deg;</h3>";

}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to convert between date formats? There are plenty of existing resources about that. Have you done any research? What did you find? In what way were existing techniques deemed unsuitable?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24170950/2610061

Comment: You can use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert UNIX timestamp to date time (javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24170933/convert-unix-timestamp-to-date-time-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean letting the user input some date+time in local format and getting UNIX timestamp for it, you can use `Date.parse()`, just it returns the milliseconds while you need seconds, so divide the result with 1000. (The base date+time is the same for both, 1970 Jan 1. 00:00:00 UTC)

```js
function doConvert(event){
  unix.textContent=Math.round(Date.parse(event.target.value)/1000);
}
```

```html
<input type="datetime-local" onchange="doConvert(event)"><br>
<div id="unix"></div>
```

If you mean the other way around (UNIX time to readable), use `Date()` (remember to convert seconds to milliseconds) and its `toLocaleString()`:

```js
function doConvert(event){
  time.textContent=new Date(event.target.valueAsNumber*1000).toLocaleString();
}
```

```html
<input type="number" oninput="doConvert(event)"><br>
<div id="time"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you advice me, how I can change this code to get the data from API and convert it?

Answer (score 0):

UnixTime = https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

```js
var UnixTime = 1525478400; 
var myDate = new Date(UnixTime*1000);
var HH = myDate.getHours(); 
var MM = myDate.getMinutes();
var SS = myDate.getSeconds();
document.write(HH+":"+MM+":"+SS);
```