# How to format UNIX timestamp to datetime in JavaScript from API?

Tags: javascript, antd

I am trying to convert UNIX time from this API into datetime to show on a chart, how could I do that? Here is the code I have:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Line } from '@ant-design/plots';
import { Card } from "antd";
import { DateTime } from 'luxon';

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    asyncFetch();
  }, []);

  const asyncFetch = () => {
    fetch('https://api.llama.fi/charts/Ethereum')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setData(json))
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('fetch data failed', error);
      });
  };

  const config = {
    data,
    padding: 'auto',
    xField: 'date',
    yField: 'totalLiquidityUSD'
```

Here is picture of the chart:

[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6daoh.png)

Comment: What is response.json?

Comment: Luxon `DateTime` has a method [fromMillis](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/parsing?id=unix-timestamps). So map your array to a new array with updated DateTime property.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24170933/convert-unix-timestamp-to-date-time-javascript

Comment: (That said, if t contains a UNIX time, all you really need is `new Date(t*1000)`, no need for external libraries

Comment: @DanielBeck I might be wrong but not `Date` but `DateTime` from Luxon, take a look at the imports in the question. But anyway

Comment: I'm talking about `Date` from vanilla javascript; there's no need to introduce an external library for this.

Answer (score 1):

multiply seconds by 1000 for ms since 1970. Then use `setTime` method of `Date` object.

```js
var ts = 1663286400
var d = new Date()
d.setTime(ts * 1000)
console.log(d)
```

Comment: I think Author is asking about his specific `DateTime` from `Luxon`, not about plain Date. Take a look at his imports

Comment: I see. I looked at the graph and figured it's only for the legend.